# Ruby why does floor method rounds to next integer

Tags: ruby

The `floor` method of [class Float](https://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/Float.html#method-i-floor) returns the next integer for large float values of only 9.

Why is that?

```
irb(main):041:0> (100.67893).floor
=> 100
irb(main):042:0> (100.99999999999999999).floor
=> 101
irb(main):043:0> (99.9999999).floor
=> 99
irb(main):044:0> (99.9999999999999999999).floor
=> 100
```

Comment: Technically for any integer x, x.999...... is equal to x + 1. In this case, floating point data types can't represent it accurately so it's actually just 100.

Comment: The thing is it only happens with repeating `9` values. Not with any other equally large or mixed values. Try this `(100.989898989898998989989899898989898989899898989).floor`

Comment: This has nothing at _all_ to do with `Float#floor`; just `99.9999999999999999999` by itself evaluates to `100.0`, presumably because the difference between the two values is too small to represent in a standard floating point value. This definitely looks like [Is floating point math broken?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/588004/is-floating-point-math-broken) to me.

Comment: @arjun : Yes, because this float is stricly less than `100.990`, so the difference to `101` is much larger than float epsilons. Ruby can tell it's nowhere near `101`, so `floor` is `100`

Comment: @philomory That's fine. Couldn't have find it for Ruby.

Comment: The number preceding `101.0` is `100.99999999999999` (call `101.0.prev_float`). If you append another `9`, the result will be closer to `101.0`  than to `100.99999999999999` and Ruby will hence return `101.0`.